# Organize typescript definitions to avoid duplicate code

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, typescript-typings, requirejs-optimizer

> Current situation:

There is a class defined in:

*lib/components/widgets/MyWidget.ts:*

```
export class MyWidget {

    public property1: string;
    /* ... more properties ... */

}
```

It gets compiled to javascript, bundled with the other files as a reult of *lib-min.js*

So because it was in the *lib/components/widgets/MyWidget.ts* i have made a definition "collection" file (*mydefinition.d.ts*) like:

```
declare module "lib/components/widgets" {
    export class MyWidget {

        /* documentation of property1 */
        public property1: string;

        /* ... more properties ... */
    }
}

interface MyOption {/* ... */}
```

In this way it can be used like (of course after including *lib-min.js* into the page):

```
import { MyWidget } from "lib/components/widgets/MyWidget";

let myInstance = new MyWidget();
```

> Problem:

I think it's obvious that maintaining this kind of duplication is overwhelming and can cause mistakes easily.
Also after upgrading to typescript 2+ (from 1.8.9) i get several compile errors for "duplicate identifiers", and generally it is not working like before.

- I could make an interface like IMyWidget and expose that to public, but then the implementation is missing and can not create with new
- I could delete the "declare module..." from the *mydefinition.d.ts* but then the module loader won't find the module (because r.js optimizer names the module from it's path)

> Question

Is there a clean and "cheap" way to solve this (and avoid code duplication if possible)?